# Coordinates of a pixel between two images

Tags: c++, qt, pixel

I am looking for a solution to easily compute the pixel coordinate from two images.

**Question:** If you take the following code, how could I compute the pixel coordinate that changed from the "QVector difference" ? Is it possible to have an (x,y) coordinate and find on the currentImage which pixel it represents ?

```
char *previousImage;
char *currentImage;
QVector difference<LONG>;

for(int i = 0 ; i < CurrentImageSize; i++)
{
    //Check if pixels are the same (we can also do it with RGB values, this is just for the example)
    if(previousImagePixel != currentImagePixel)
    {
        difference.push_back(currentImage - previousImage);
    }
    currentImage++;
}
```

**EDIT:**
More information about this topic:

- The image is in RGB format
- The width, the height and the bpp of both images are known
- I have a pointer to the bytes representing the image

The main objective here is to clearly know what is the new value of a pixel that changed between the two images and to know which pixel is it (its coordinates)

Comment: Assuming those char pointers are flat buffers holding your pixels...if you know the dimensions of the image, you can calculate the (x,y) coordinate from the offset of the current pixel into the array.

Comment: @melak47 Yes we can easily make that assumption and yes I know the dimension of both images which in this case are the same. Then, how with the offset of the current pixel, could I calculate the coordinates ?

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit do you mean you want to know where one intensity value of a pixel, in previousImage, went on currentImage?

Comment: @carmellose I mean I would like to know which pixel on the current image have change compared with the previous one so it is what you were saying actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not enough information to answer, but I will try to give you some idea.

You have declared `char *previousImage;`, which implies to me that you have a pointer to the bytes representing an image.  You need more than that to interpret the image.

1. You need to know the pixel format. You mention RGB, So -- for the time being, let's assume that the image uses 3 bytes for each pixel and the order is RGB
2. You need to know the width of the image.
3. Given the above 2, you can calculate the "Row Stride", which is the number of bytes that a row takes up.  This is usually the "bytes per pixel" * "image width", but it is typically padded out to be divisible by 4.  So 3 bpp and a width of 15, would be 45 bytes + 3 bytes of padding to make the row stride 48.
4. Given that, if you have an index into the image data, you first integer-divide it against the row stride to get the row  (Y coordinate).
5. The X coordinate is the (index mod the row stride) integer-divided by the bytes per pixel.

Comment: I forgot to give some elements to this topic... So yes it is RGB, I know the width, the height and the bpp of both images and as you said it, I have a pointer to the bytes representing the image. WHat you mean by index into the image data is the LONG variable stored in the QVector difference ?

Comment: @RobertJones Instead of commenting, *please amend your question*. Remember: your question *has to stand on its own* without any comments. If it doesn't, it's deficient and off-topic here.

Comment: I've just followed your 5 steps and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much for your help and precious advice

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want compute the displacement or motion that occured between two images. E.g. for each pixel `I(x, y, t=previous)` in `previousImage`, you want to know where it did go in `currentImage`, and what is his new coordinate `I(x, y, t=current)`.

If that is the case, then it's called [motion estimation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_estimation) and measuring the [optical flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_flow). There are many algorithms for that, who rely on more or less complex hypotheses, depending on the objects you observe in the image sequence.

The simpliest hypothesis is that if you follow a *moving* pixel `I(x, y, t)` in the scene you observe, its luminance will remain constant over time. In other words, `dI(x,y,t) / dt = 0`.

Since `I(x, y, t)` is function of three parameters (space and time) with two unknowns, and there is only one equation, this is an ill defined problem that has no easy solution. Many of the algorithms add an additional hypothesis, so that the problem can be solved with a unique solution.

You can use existing libraries which will do that for you, one of them which is pretty popular is [openCV](http://opencv.org/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, with the little amount of elements I gave when creating this post, you misunderstood me. The main goal here is not to compute the coordinates of a specific pixel between two images for motion estimation but if between two consecutive frame there is a pixel that is different to be able to compute the coordinates of this pixel.

Comment: @RobertJones Then I guess you just need to do a loop on `currentImage` and check if, for each pixel at coordinates (x,y), the value in `difference` at coordinates (x,y) is not null. If it isn't, it means that it's the pixel (x,y) 'moved' between `previousImage` and `currentImage`. Otherwise, I might have missed something :p